# How can I add my Github Project to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, repository

I am trying to add my project to eclipse, but it is giving me a not authorised error even after providing all proper credentials.
Its my private repository and my two factor authentication is also enabled.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: @Arpit the errors are follows:- 
1) https://github.com/xyz:not authorised
2) An error occured when trying to contact https://github.com/xyz
3) Possible reasons :-
 a) Incorrect url
 b) No network connection
 c) SSL host could not be verified(set https.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)

Comment: Since you mentioned your two factor authentication is enabled, it might be that you have to enter, not the password, but the personal access token. Have you tried using that (Can be found under https://github.com/settings/tokens). If you do not have one, generate one and try with that.

Comment: yes i get 6 digit two factor authentication code...you mean i should enter that code in password section in eclipse??

Comment: No, if you go to the URL I mentioned above - github.com/settings/tokens (from the browser where you are logged in) you would see some personal access tokens (alphanumeric, definitely longer than 6 digits). If you do not have any, you would get an option to generate these. You can try to enter that in eclipse to see if that works.

Comment: ok i'll try it and let you know! but really thank you for taking time and helping me @Arpit

Comment: hey @Arpit, it worked! Thank you very much...Thanks a lot!!